# Send Location by Telegram API client

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-api

I use TLSharp lib. How can i send my location to user. i known how to send simple text message, but cant understand how share my geoposition.

```
var store = new FileSessionStore();
            var client = new TelegramClient(api_id, api_hash, store,"session");
            await client.ConnectAsync(); 
...   
await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = userByPhoneId.Id }, "Simple mess");
```

I create request :

```
        TLInputPeerUser ip = new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = user.Id };
        
        TLInputMediaGeoPoint igp = new TLInputMediaGeoPoint();
        igp.GeoPoint = new TLInputGeoPoint() { Lat= ..., Long= ...};
        
       
        var req = new TLRequestSendMedia()
        {
            Media = igp ,
            Peer = ip,
            RandomId = 


    };

        await client.SendRequestAsync<Boolean>(req);
```

But it's not works, because value RandomId was needed. Random Id have long type, i try to generate random long number but it's not helped , i receive error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var req = new TLRequestSendMedia()
            {
                Media = igp,
                Peer = ip,
                RandomId = Helpers.GenerateRandomLong()


            };

            await client.SendRequestAsync<TLAbsUpdates>(req);
```